# Soldering 2-Wire DC Motor directly to PCB

Tags: pcb, dc-motor, pcb-assembly

I'm making a PCB that's required to be pretty compact. In order to reduce overall size, I need to keep [a 2-wire DC motor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XWM2Q2B) as close to a PCB as possible.

It has standard tabs on the back, typically for soldering wires to. I've been looking all over for ways to solder a DC motor directly to a PCB. Unfortunately. what makes this more difficult is that the motor needs to lie parallel with the board, not perpendicular, and it sits at the edge of the board:
[image]

I've looked at some terminal blocks and crimp connectors to plug the wires into, but preferably the motor sits right up against the PCB, and either gets soldered on or the metal tabs just plug in.

Please let me know your thoughts!
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keystone 3557  looks like a possible PCB mount recptacle for the motor tabs.

[image]

source keystone catalogue page
https://www.keyelco.com/userAssets/file/M65p61.pdf

Comment: These look great! I'll order a few of them and try them out.